# Can my program or script ask Windows 10 about keyboard or mouse activity?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to write a program or script that looks at how long the user has been idle.  How long since the last keyboard or mouse activity.  What features of Windows 10 can I use for that?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. SuperUser is not a "please write me a script" kind of site, and furthermore this question would be better answered on StackOverflow as they're for the enthusiastic programmers. That said, there are API calls you can make to find out if a user is using the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Windows API function [`GetLastInputInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns the time of the last input event in milliseconds.

It's not system-wide across all running sessions, but provides information for the current session only. It's supported from Windows 2000 up.